How to execute history command by number in Alpine Linux (busybox, ash)?
Is it possible to execute a history command by number with !###, similar to bash/zsh? Alpine's ash shell does not interpret this:
$ history
1441 date
1442 history

$ !1141
-sh: !1141: not found


As this is Busybox Alpine Linux, no, there is not.
If this were regular Alpine Linux, then the fc utility can be used to execute commands from history via the line number. For example:
alpinelinux:~$ uptime
18:09:45 up 10:17,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
alpinelinux:~$ history | grep 'uptime'
62  uptime
63  history | grep 'uptime'
alpinelinux:~$ fc -s 62
uptime
 18:09:58 up 10:18,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

That command doesn't exist in Busybox.

There is the POSIX utility fc(1p), which is in mksh used in the aliases history as \\builtin fc -l and r as \\builtin fc -e - , which is similar to Bash's !.

However, fc is not listed among the supported commands on the Busybox's website, so it seems that Busybox's ash doesn't support that command (yet?).

Related link to the mksh manual.

@Vilinkameni Rather than just posting a link, provide an explanation of what you referring to or if it is meant to be useful in regards to the question, post it as an answer and explain it there.

Also the direct link to the source code of dot.mkshrc. The alias r is clearly defined as \\builtin fc -e - . Running eg. vim some.file; r vim=ed will run ed some.file in mksh, after running vim some.file.

@Vilinkameni Your point? None of that is needed. If one just wants to run a command from a line of the history, then fc -s # is sufficient. There is no need go through that much effort to do something that is quite simple. fc isn't available in Busybox anyway or else the person asking the question would have used it.

As I've said, the fc utility can be used to achieve functionality similar to Bash's csh-like history expansion (including !123, which is r 123 in mksh, !?cat, which is r cat in mksh, and ^cat^less, which is r cat=less in mksh), but currently not in ash. Another "point" is that fc -e - both is the definition of alias r in mksh, and it works as described above, with no editor executed (regarding your comment on fc -s).

@Vilinkameni I've covered that for regular Alpine Linux and all of that still isn't needed for what the question is looking for. You said yourself that it doesn't exist in Busybox anyway. Otherwise, post what you have as an answer and not a comment.

⚠️ @vilinkameni This conversation is too verbose. If there's another answer, kindly post it so we can vote on it - keep it simple and don't add unnecessary complexity
